# Using rack-cors with Rackspace CDN issues

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cors, rack, font-awesome, rackspace

I have a rails 4.2 app using [rack-cors](https://github.com/cyu/rack-cors). None of my font-awesome icons show up even though all my other assets are fine. I'm using the rackspace cdn. My CDN url looks something like

```
http://ddf908e003b5678bc25-9d6bfcdc12345678ba868a15bca98.r12.cf5.rackcdn.com/assets/main-4f3595479ce96112e1b8ab4e5357fc26.css
```

My rack-cors config is in my `config/application.rb`

```
config.middleware.insert_before 0, "Rack::Cors" do
  allow do
    origins 'localhost:3000', /^http:\/\/\w+.+rackcdn.com/
    resource '/assets/*', headers: :any, methods: :get
  end
end
```

The icons show up locally just fine. It's only in production that they don't show. Any ideas on what I might be missing?

**EDIT**

I'm using the [font-awesome-sass](https://github.com/FortAwesome/font-awesome-sass) gem. When I view the page, I don't get any javascript errors or anything, just the CORS warning, and no icons.

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://ddf908e003b5678bc25-9d6bfcdc12345678ba868a15bca98.r12.cf5.rackcdn.com/assets/main-4f3595479ce96112e1b8ab4e5357fc26.css/assets/font-awesome/fontawesome-webfont-e9c0e802c2b0faf4d660e2bff17b5cf1.woff. This can be fixed by moving the resource to the same domain or enabling CORS.
```

**EDIT 2**

I'm using [asset_sync](https://github.com/rumblelabs/asset_sync) to help set the custom headers that Ash Wilson suggested doing.

```
AssetSync.configure do |config|
  config.fog_provider = 'Rackspace'
  config.rackspace_username = ENV['RACKSPACE_USERNAME']
  config.rackspace_api_key = ENV['RACKSPACE_API_KEY']
  config.fog_directory = ENV['FOG_DIRECTORY']
  config.fog_region = ENV['FOG_REGION']
  config.gzip_compression = true
  config.manifest = true
  config.custom_headers = {
    "\.(ttf|otf|eot|woff|svg)$" => {
      "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" => "*",
      "Access-Control-Request-Method" => "*",
      "Access-Control-Allow-Methods" => "*"
    }
  }
end
```

I'm not doing any cacheing on my end just yet, but I was sure to clear any browser cache. I also found the 2 files complaining `.woff` and `.ttf` in the Control panel as Ash had mentioned below, and I added the headers manually into that. However, I'm still seeing the same issue. Maybe there's an additional step, or possibly AssetSync is just dead and doesn't work?

**EDIT 3**

Here are the headers from a curl. Looks like the CORS headers are in there. Waited all day for propagation, but still no go.

```
curl -i -s -XHEAD http://ddf908e003b5678bc25-9d6bfcdc12345678ba868a15bca98.r12.cf5.rackcdn.com/assets/font-awesome/fontawesome-webfont-e0e0f28a0197446b28f818aa81b80530.ttf

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Length: 112160
Last-Modified: Thu, 07 May 2015 16:49:12 GMT
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Access-Control-Request-Method: *
ETag: c4668ed2440df82d3fd2f8be9d31d07d
X-Timestamp: 1431017351.82062
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, HEAD, OPTIONS
Content-Type: application/font-sfnt
X-Trans-Id: tx53b90a9b638141c6874e6-00554bf992iad3
Cache-Control: public, max-age=259200
Expires: Sun, 10 May 2015 23:47:30 GMT
Date: Thu, 07 May 2015 23:47:30 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
```

Comment: Have you checked the JavaScript console to see if your resources are coming through? There may be error messages. Also, font-awesome requires your font files to be served, so make sure you're serving that through the CDN, not just CSS and JavaScript.

Comment: I'm not getting any errors, just the CORS warning. I've updated my question to include some additional info.

Comment: This probably isn't a problem with your headers. It's probably with the Rackspace headers. Can you use "curl -v" on the URL to print out the headers? If Rackspace CDN isn't setting the right CORS headers, I'm not sure how you can fix that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get CORS working properly, you'll need to set the CORS headers on the Cloud Files object on Rackspace's end, rather than the ones served by your app. You can do this from the [control panel](https://mycloud.rackspace.com/) by clicking on the gear icon next to each file:

[image: control panel]

The [Cloud Files documentation](http://docs.rackspace.com/files/api/v1/cf-devguide/content/Assigning_CORS_Headers_to_Requests-d1e2120.html) includes a section on the CORS headers that are supported and what each means.

If you have a large number of assets, or a build process that publishes them automatically, you'll want to use the API or an SDK to set these instead. The [developer documentation](https://developer.rackspace.com/docs/cloud-files/getting-started/#change-object-metadata) includes a code snippet that you can adopt to do this; substitute "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" or the other relevant headers for "Content-Type".

Here's a complete example using the Ruby SDK, Fog:

```
require 'fog'

# Authenticate
@client = Fog::Storage.new(
  :provider => 'rackspace',
  :rackspace_username => '{username}',
  :rackspace_api_key => '{apiKey}',
  :rackspace_region => '{region}'
)

# Find the file object
@directory = @client.directories.get("{container name}")
@file = @directory.get("{file name}")

# To only allow CORS requests from a page hosted at 'my-domain.com'
# You can also set this to '*' to allow CORS requests from anywhere
@file.access_control_allow_origin = "http://my-domain.com"
@file.save
```

Comment: I appreciate the really detailed answer. Unfortunately, I'm still having the same issue. Not caching anything on my end, but cleared all browser cache just in case. Manually set the headers in the control panel for testing. I'm using AssetSync. I'll update my question to show latest changes

Comment: Hmm. I didn't think that you'd need to wait for header changes to propagate to the CDN like you do for content changes, but I could be mistaken. Can you try using a new container ("directory")?

Comment: Another way to check for the headers is to use curl with the public http or https URLs:

  curl -i -s -X HEAD http://...

Comment: I thought the same thing. I let it sit most the day, but still nothing. I updated my question with the results of the curl.

Comment: oh, it's showing up! I guess I was just too impatient and didn't wait long enough! Thanks!!